# Wordpress: Add WPForms shortcodes to PHP templates and pass custom data

Tags: php, wordpress, wpforms

I have a shortcode in my php template that displays some posts of type "services". On each of these posts, I want to add a button that opens a form for email before download (the user enters an email address and clicks on the download button to download a file). Now for each post, the form would download a different file. I can add a button and open the WPForm using the shortcode in the PHP template. I am not sure how I can send the URL of the file to WPform that can be downloaded on form submit.